# Dual Booting Mistakes & Installation Headaches

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

#### Please forgive me; I will attempt to keep this as short and to the point as possible

---

***Pre-Context:***

So initially, my laptop was dual booting *Windows 10* & *Linux Mint* (*this was my first instance in learning anything in regards to linux operating systems*) Now after about 9 months of learning as much as i can about linux operating systems, and after much trial and error dilemmas, i had come to the conclusion that i wanted to switch to *Ubuntu 19.04*

Normally when i would boot my laptop, i would select F9 (*select boot device*) which is when i would select my internal hard drive (*labelled as "Notebook Hard Drive"*) ..fallowing which i would be brought to the Grub2 menu where i would choose between *Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon* & *Windows 10 Pro*

One evening after work, in a fit of impatience i decided to simply delete the Linux Mint partitions from existence! (trial & error LOL) Now, I'm sure you all know what happens next? I was regrettably left with an un-bootable windows. After many hours trouble shooting and pain staking calls to computer techs that seem to have less experience then myself in Linux -.- I cease to find a solution to my problem.

So.. i then come up with this great idea! What if i were to install Ubuntu, alongside my Win10 partitions? Thinking to myself that maybe that would reinstall grub *thinking i was a genius at this moment would be an understatement LOL*

So i create the Ubuntu 19.04 boot-able USB, and away i go! After the installation, which didn't go necessarily as planned, i learned this in-fact did not solve my problem! (during the installation i was required to make a EFI partition manually, which i did totalling 500mb. After-which i was able to install Ubuntu. It was recommended that i install Ubuntu on a singular partition of / which i did so)

Moving forward however, this did not solve my initial problem of having an un-bootable windows.. and now there was a second problem that had arisen.. When i boot my laptop, i begin to fallow the steps to which i have become accustomed to; being i select F9 and select my hard drive. Before i select my hard drive i notice that Ubuntu itself has it own selection right there in the "F9-Select Boot Device Menu" ..alittle confused i proceeded to select my hard drive just because id rather stick with what i know at this point in time. However, this failed to boot, just as it did after initially deleting the Mint partitions.

So i restart my PC, this time selecting Ubuntu itself from the boot device menu. However, this also will not boot. So after alittle investigation and brain storming, i had gone back to the boot device menu and noticed that alongside my "Notebook Hard Drive" & "Ubuntu" selections, there was a 3rd option to which i was able to select;  "Boot From EFI" which after selecting, i would navigate thru finally discovering how to boot my Ubuntu installation (a procedure i have to fallow when booting Ubuntu every single time to this very moment..

*Someone had said to me that it sounded like Windows was installed on BIOS and Ubuntu was installed on EFI* ???

Lastly i went to visit a family member today, and while i was there i decided to create a new Windows 10 Media Creation Tool USB.. (i did have a DVD-RW with Windows 10 burned to it however i figured maybe an up-to-date USB would be better) after all, all bootrec attempts to save my windows installation have failed when using the DVD-RW so figured newer was better aha

I have initially decided to install Windows 10 onto my 750GB Ext HDD (USB) which when attempted, said my EXT HDD was unable to install Windows onto due to the fact that it was not GPT. So i boot BACK INTO Ubuntu and open GParted and convert my EXT HDD to GPT. Which i reboot back into my freshly made Win10 Creation Tool USB and discover that i get the error stating

*"SETUP DOES NOT SUPPORT CONFIGURATION OF OR INSTALLATION TO DISKS CONNECTED THRU A USB OR IEEE 1394 PORT"*

My main reason for installing Windows 10 on my external you may be wondering? Well there is a-lot of software that is currently on my Internal Win10 installation that i direly do not wish to lose. If i have to, then so be it, however i would like to exhaust every possible solution. (i,e, EASE-US Trans PC, Creating a "System Image" somehow even tho my Windows isn't bootable, even a software called MRI to which i was suggest from someone else i know)

Please forgive me if this is confusing, as i am very much an amateur myself to say the least, i am attempting to word this as best as i can. I can provide further information if needed! Do not hesitate to ask.

Virtualbox Doesnt Seem To Be Working Either

Comment: That's sweet but not short. And after reading all this I still wonder what your question actually is.

Comment: At first, what lead me to you lovely folks at AskUbuntu was my dilemma with installing Windows onto my external hard drive. I seemed to have "maybe" found a solution online but that entails me using WinToUSB which is a Windows software which means i cannot do so while using Ubuntu.. Honestly my brain is just numb lol all-in-all any help in regards to any of my twenty dilemmas would be appreciated.

Comment: How to install Windows on your external drive is definitely off-topic, here we only support Ubuntu and it's official derivates. But have you seen https://askubuntu.com/questions/919273/install-windows-on-external-hard-drive ?

Comment: thats just it.. it is, and it isnt off topic.. how would i use ubuntu os, to install windows on ext (wouldnt that be a question for Ubuntu users?) I mean no disrespect, just being thurough! Maybe an alternative to WinToUSB to Ubuntu

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919273/install-windows-on-external-hard-drive

Currently in the proccess of trying.. i started that before posting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you accidentally didn't destroy the entire Windows bootloader, which given what you have shared I don't *think* you have, it seems like GRUB is not seeing the Windows bootloader. I suggest trying the boot-repair utility and if that isn't the magic program you need, look through the debug logs for important info you could share here. From a Live Session, try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Follow the instructions it shows and it *might* just work, in the off chance it doesn't, it'll dump some logs you can look through.